# Incrementing a number more than once from a variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, counter, increment

How would go about adding multiple values to another value so that it increments?

For example every time a variable gets a new value, add that value to a main total, incrementing it like a counter. So if a value changes to 4, then to 5 then to 2 the incremented total value would be 11.

Is it along the lines of '++' or '=+'?

Ive tried to get it working with a simple example below:

Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).

```
 <script>

 var blue;
 var green = 3;
 var yellow = 3;

 blue =+ green;
 blue =+ yellow;

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=blue;

 </script>
```

So i would want blue to now have the value of 6.

Thank you.

Comment: This is far from the only thing you need to know, but it's `+=`, not `=+`.

Comment: And also you have to initialize correctly `var blue = 0;`

Comment: @Pointy ah thankyou. i tried it in my example and got NaN but realised I hadnt declared my blue variable as an integer, which gave me what i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @freakish yeah realised afterwards thanks.

Comment: @jord49 If you have solved this problem, either add the solution as an answer yourself and accept it, or delete the question. The former is preferable if it will help other people learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand it here. As for your example you described, you can easily use `+=` to implement.

```
 <script>

 var blue;
 var green = 3;
 var yellow = 3;

 blue += green;
 blue += yellow;

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=blue;

 </script>
```

Then the blue will be 6 here.

But from the description at the beginning, I guess you mean you want something like this:

```
var blue = 0;
var mainCount = 0;
blue = 3;
blue = 9;
blue = 1;
//Then the mainCount will automatically be 13
```

If this is what you want here, you might need something a little bit complicate for javascript. You need to write a function to set the value of blue, then you can do extra things every time you set the value. Like this:

```
var blue = 0;
var mainCount = 0;
var setBlue = function(value) {blue = value; mainCount += blue;};

setBlue(3); //blue is 3, mainCount is 3
setBlue(9); //blue is 9, mainCount is 12
setBlue(1); //blue is 1, mainCount is 13
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

+= was the wrong way round and should have been +=.

Needed to initialise the 'var blue' correctly as it needed to be an integer, so corrected to var blue = 0;

Many thanks for the comments.